# ROS Answers SE migration: UDP in rospy

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've got a client that keep sending info over UDP so I've seen rospy has a class named UDPROSTransport that can receive UDP mensagens, is this class working? I'm quite confuse about how to properly use it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39816/udp-in-rospy/) by [borth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2921/borth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as as I am aware the python implementation of UDPROS is non-existent/incomplete. See below.

[1] https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/1023

[2] http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/ROSUDP-in-ROSPY-td2756461.html

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [borth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2921/borth/) on 2012-07-26**:
So, if its non-existent/incomplete, would there be any problems if I make the UDP connection through the socket class of python or ROS wouldn't accept well it?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-07-26**:
@borth: Does your client send UDP packets outside the ROS ecosystem? i.e. is the client sending raw UDP packets directly? If so, then using the Socket class is the best solution anyway. On the other hand, if the client is a C++ ROS node sending UDP, a ton of work is required to receive messages.